# "Sent" Email Disappeared; No swoosh sound

Tags: macbook-pro, email

Macbook Pro Mojave 10.14.6

Yesterday I composed an email w/2 attachments [46MB].  I clicked the Send arrow at top of email but did not hear swoosh sound.

I checked all Sent boxes but this email was not in any mailbox.  I contacted Applecare tech support but they could not find it on my system.

The email has not been rejected/returned and I haven’t heard from intended recipient as to whether he received it.

How can I be sure the email was sent out as intended?

Comment: Which email service did you use? Are  large attachments to be sent with mail drop  enabled for that account ?  One way to make sure about delivery would have been to bcc yourself. But for this one, outbox is the only place it should be in.

Comment: 46 MB in an email which is also quite weird to do. Anyway, check your Outbox. It should be there. Once you have a large MB file, your email will go to Outbox first till it manages to send it.